# How to use css filter: blur() property in React native on a text element?

Tags: react-native

I need to add a blur effect on a text.

If I were using React, I would use the filter css property.

But I can't find the equivalent syntax to use it in a React native stylesheet.

How do i need to write it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can install react-native-blur / expo-blur
2. If it's not working for you, this is a workaround/hack that clones the look of blurry text. You can adjust the values to your liking.

   <View
   style={{
   height: 3,
   width: 70,
   shadowOpacity: 1,
   shadowColor: '#000',
   shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
   shadowRadius: 5,
   elevation: 5,
   borderWidth: 0.5,
   borderColor: "white",
   backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
   }}
   />